# How to update HTML in inactive chrome tab with extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently trying to make a Chrome extension, and I've ran into a problem where I don't know how to update HTML from an inactive tab. I'm trying to periodically access the HTML of a Google Meet in an inactive tab, to detect when people leave or join the call. However, document.querySelector only works when the tab is focused, as if it's not, it will just keep giving the same info from the last time it was focused, even if people have left or joined the call since then. Is there any way to detect these changes without having to focus the tab? Here is what I've tried in my code:

background.js

```
meetTab = []
// check for google meet tabs
function query()
{
    meetTab = []
    chrome.tabs.query({url: "https://meet.google.com/*-*"},function(tabs)
    {
        tabs.forEach(function(tab)
        {
            meetTab.push(tab)
        });
    })
}
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(query)
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(query)
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(query)
setInterval(send, 3000)
// execute script for each google meet tab every 3 sec
function send()
{

    meetTab.forEach(function(tab)
    {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "check.js"})
    })
}
// this part only prints updated info when meet tab is active
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(message)
});
```

check.js

```
// element to be tracked
thing = document.querySelector("#ow3 > div.T4LgNb > div > div:nth-child(9) > div.crqnQb > div.rG0ybd.xPh1xb.P9KVBf.LCXT6 > div.TqwH9c > div.SZfyod > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div")
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({msg:thing.innerText})
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Meet Kicker",
  "version": "1.0",
  "icons": {"128": "bigicon.png"},
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "smallicon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["storage", "tabs", "<all_urls>"],

  "background":
  {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

Updated check.js trying to use MutationObserver

```
thing = document.querySelector("#ow3 > div.T4LgNb > div > div:nth-child(9) > div.crqnQb > div.rG0ybd.xPh1xb.P9KVBf.LCXT6 > div.TqwH9c > div.SZfyod > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div")

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({msg:thing.innerText})

      });
    });

observer.observe(thing, { characterData: true, attributes: false, childList: false, subtree: true });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd review things a little.

Doing a bit of order may perhaps solve the problem.

First thing I'd remove the "onRemoved" event handler which I don't see how it can serve the purpose.

Then  I'd review the "onCreated" event handler so as not to re-inject the content script (CS) into all tabs which contain Google Meet (GM) but only to the newly opened tab
(only if GM is obviously loaded in this latter).

I'd add the **onUpdate** event handler because if a tab is updated by loading GM inside it then it's good to inject the CS where it was not there before.

Let's talk now about the setInterval (which could be the cause of all\many of your problems).
Here we need to understand one thing (I state that I do not know much GM).
**Q1**: Does the node you want to check through querySelector lies in the page where you have already injected the CS or stays in a (i)frame?
**Q2**: Does the page or (i)frame containing that node reload over time? (you can see this with devtools Network panel or by using event handler such as tabs.onUpdate or webNavigation.onComplete)

If the monitored node belongs to a page that is reloaded periodically then it is right to re-inject the CS periodically.
(**which you can manage inside the onUpdate event handler and not with  setInterval**).

If, on the other hand, the page that contains (or will contain) the node is not reloaded and therefore the node appears in a moment that cannot be determined a priori
then you don't have to re-inject but "observe" the mutations of the DOM (in practice you have to use the **MutationObsever** object).

Lastly, I advise you to check if you have installed extensions that optimize the CPU and memory and that could somehow interfere with your code.

Comment: I tried changing it to use onUpdated instead of setInterval to inject the script, and after running it a bunch I found out that onUpdated is also called when someone joins the google meet, but not when they leave, presumably because of the sound that the tab makes when someone joins since there isn't one when someone leaves? Anyways, I tried using MutationObserver, and unfortunately it only seemed to fire when the tab was active. If I was on a another tab, the listener wouldn't be called until I switch back to the google meet tab for it to detect any change. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: Oh and I checked, and I'm pretty sure the node I'm checking isn't in any sort of frame? I'm just not sure where to go from here as it just seems like the HTML of the tab doesn't update until I select it, except for that case with the onUpdated detecting when people join the meet.

Comment: According to what you've stated, I confirm the guidelines. Inject the CS every time the page is reloaded and wherever you want; the important thing is that you don't lose track of your node (the path you use for querySelector must remain constant). If you have to deal with multiple frames it'd be better inject selectively in order to avoid multiple messages between CS and background script. In the CS you immediately check if the node is present and then delegate the "waiting work" to the "observer".

Comment: It's possible that new participants make the page reload, while contacts who leave the room don't reload the page, but only change the DOM. You can verify this through the Network panel of devtools simulating a person who leaves and join a room. It is also possible that every time a participant leaves the group he doesn't trigger the mutationObserver at least until the tab becomes active. This behavior may have been deliberately designed in GM; if so, I know you can do very little about it. You cannot activate a tab without do not making it active.